Get woocommerce orders from 4 hours ago - Wordpress
I currently have a custom code that gives me the ids of all the orders and it works well.
(This code gives you the ID of a product and gives you all the orders for the product.)
This is:
function get_orders_ids_by_product_id( $product_id, $order_status = ['wc-completed', 'wc-processing'] ){
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_col("
SELECT order_items.order_id
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as order_items
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID
WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
AND posts.post_status IN ( '" . implode( "','", $order_status ) . "' )
AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_product_id'
AND order_item_meta.meta_value = '$product_id'
");
return count($results);
}

However I need to filter the orders that were placed in a range of 0 to 4 hours maximum.
I tried putting this in the query but was unsuccessful.
WHERE post_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 4 HOUR)

Code not working
function get_orders_ids_by_product_id( $product_id, $order_status = ['wc-completed', 'wc-processing'] ){
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_col("
SELECT order_items.order_id
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as order_items
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID
WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
WHERE post_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 4 HOUR)
AND posts.post_status IN ( '" . implode( "','", $order_status ) . "' )
AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_product_id'
AND order_item_meta.meta_value = '$product_id'
");
return count($results);
}

What am I doing wrong?

AND posts.post_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR) as any additional conditions

It looks like the issue is happens because of incorrect placement of Where clause and usage of post_date column.
I suggest you to use DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR) with the help of that we can subtracts 4 hours from the current date and time, which will gives you a date time that is 4 hours ago from now, so could you please update the value of $result in your code, it should work for you.
$results = $wpdb->get_col("
        SELECT order_items.order_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as order_items
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID
        WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND posts.post_status IN ( '" . implode( "','", $order_status ) . "' )
        AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_value = '$product_id'
        AND posts.post_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR)
    ");


It works as I see, but with a 1 hour delay from what I see, the now function delivers 1 hour ahead of my time zone.
How can I convert now() to gmt -5?
Thanks

You should be able to do that with the help of CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '+00:00', '-05:00')

It is insecure practice to directly write variables into a SQL string.
